# Функция в качестве аргумента функции. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, функции

Я изучаю JavaScript, купил для этого книги. И вот дошел к разделу "Функции в качестве аргумента другой функции". Помимо небольшого параграфа с объяснениями, был вот такой листинг, который я не до конца понял. Я начал разбирать его буквально на листе бумаги, пытаясь понять как получается конечный результат. Но возникли вопросы, которые я попытался выразить в комментариях кода. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```js
// Мы задаём в качестве аргумента x значение z. => x == z
function diff(f, x, dx) {
  return (f(x + dx) - f(x)) / dx; // x = z = 1, dx = 0,001 (аргумент функции). (1 + 0,001 - 1) / 0,001 
  // результат = 1
}

function G(x) { //  результат = x в этой функции = 1
  return x * x + x; // 1 * 1 + 1 = 2
}

function g(x) { // это не трогаем, это для сравнения
  return 2 * x + 1;
}
document.write("<h4>Вычисление производной</h4>")
var z = 1;
document.write(g(z) + " vs " + diff(G, z, 0.001) + "<br>"); // по результату расчетов, g(x) = 3, G(x) = 2
// а результат в браузере такой: g(x) = 3 G(x) = 3.0009999999993653
// у меня претензии и не понимание в уравнении (f(x + dx) - f(x))/dx. Какое бы значение z не имела бы,
// результат этой функции будет всегда 1. Почему? x и -x из уравнения сократим, а 0,001/0,001 = 1
// но результат в браузере совсем иначий. Как так происходит? Где я ошибаюсь?
```

Comment: как ты "сокращаешь" аргументы функций? `f(x+y)` очень редко совпадает со значением `f(x)+f(y)`

Comment: А где ты y нашел? тут только x

Comment: `f(x + dx)` что по твоему тут написано?

Comment: Ну 1 + 0,001 = 1,001. Дальше отнимаем единицу же f(x)? Или в этом подвох: нельзя так делать?

Comment: _Ну 1 + 0,001 = 1,001._ - и получил `f(1.001) - f(1)` где ты тут нашел 1 чтобы ее вычесть, непонятно

Comment: Хорошо, и что "на листе бумаги" с этим уравнением происходит дальше? Я считал, что тогда 1,001 - 1

Comment: _Я считал, что тогда 1,001 - 1_ - это было бы так, если бы твоя функция была такой: `f(x) = x`, а у тебя она `f(x) = x*x+x`

Comment: Тогда какие числа подставляем под x * x + x?

Comment: те, которые ты передаешь в функцию `f` :)

Comment: Кажется я понял. Проверил на калькуляторе результат. Сошлось. Спасибо большое

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var z = 1;
console.log( g(z) + " vs " + diff(G, z, 0.001) ); 

function diff(f, x, dx) {
  return (f(x + dx) - f(x)) / dx;
  /*    G(1 + 0.001)
             ↓
        G( 1.001 ) → 1.001 * 1.001 + 1.001 == 2.003001
  минус G( 1 )     → 1 * 1 + 1             == 2
      
      На выходе должно быть (2.003001 - 2) / 0.001 
      На калькуляторе - одно, а в JS - будет другое.
      Поэтому точные вычисления не делаются на JS
   */
}

console.log( (2.003001 - 2) / 0.001 );

function G(x) {
  return x * x + x; 
}

function g(x) { 
  return 2 * x + 1;
}
```

Можно найти много чего интересного по запросу [0.1 + 0.2 javascript](https://www.google.com/search?q=0.1+%2B+0.2+javascript&rlz=1C1CHBF_enAM856AM856&oq=0.1+%2B+0.2&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j6j0l3.2237j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ))

Но достаточно знать, что возможны незначительные косяки при вычислениях, если есть нецелые числа. И перед окончательным выводом результата, дополнительно округлять его для страховки. А c точным вычислениями - уже не к JS)